Unable to compile Apache TVM runtime for MIPS platform
I am trying to build Apache TVM library for MIPs platform using steps explained on this page for RISC.
Following are the steps I followed:
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install g++-9-multilib-mips-linux-gnu

$ sudo apt-get install gcc-9-mips-linux-gnu

$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/tvm tvm

$ cd tvm

$ mkdir build

$ cp cmake/config.cmake build

$ cd build

$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=1 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-g++-9 -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/usr/mips-linux-gnu -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=ONLY -DMACHINE_NAME=mips-linux-gnu

$ make -j8 runtime

But I ended up getting following errors / FATAL warnings:
In file included from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/io.h:443,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/include/tvm/runtime/module.h:29,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/include/tvm/runtime/packed_func.h:34,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/include/tvm/runtime/disco/session.h:77,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/include/tvm/runtime/disco/disco_worker.h:28,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/process_session.cc:20:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h: In instantiation of ‘static bool dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Read(dmlc::Stream*, T*) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:66:22:   recursively required from ‘static bool dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Read(dmlc::Stream*, T*) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::NativePODHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:66:22:   required from ‘static bool dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Read(dmlc::Stream*, T*) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::ArithmeticHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::NativePODHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:294:11:   required from ‘static bool dmlc::serializer::Handler<T>::Read(dmlc::Stream*, T*) [with T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/io.h:453:38:   required from ‘bool dmlc::Stream::Read(T*) [with T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/./message_queue.h:98:21:   required from here
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:66:22: error: ‘Read’ is not a member of ‘dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>’
   66 |     return Else::Read(strm, data);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h: In instantiation of ‘static void dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Write(dmlc::Stream*, const T&) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:63:16:   recursively required from ‘static void dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Write(dmlc::Stream*, const T&) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::NativePODHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:63:16:   required from ‘static void dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, Then, Else, T>::Write(dmlc::Stream*, const T&) [with Then = dmlc::serializer::ArithmeticHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; Else = dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::NativePODHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::IfThenElse<false, dmlc::serializer::SaveLoadClassHandler<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>, tvm::runtime::RPCCode>; T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:275:16:   required from ‘static void dmlc::serializer::Handler<T>::Write(dmlc::Stream*, const T&) [with T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/io.h:449:32:   required from ‘void dmlc::Stream::Write(const T&) [with T = tvm::runtime::RPCCode]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/../minrpc/rpc_reference.h:545:5:   required from ‘static void tvm::runtime::RPCReference::ReturnPackedSeq(const TVMValue*, const int*, int, TChannel*) [with TChannel = tvm::runtime::DiscoStreamMessageQueue]’
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/./message_queue.h:39:84:   required from here
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/serializer.h:63:16: error: ‘Write’ is not a member of ‘dmlc::serializer::UndefinedSerializerFor<tvm::runtime::RPCCode>’
   63 |     Else::Write(strm, data);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/././protocol.h:35,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/./message_queue.h:26,
                 from /home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/process_session.cc:34:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/././../../support/base64.h: In member function ‘virtual size_t tvm::support::Base64OutStream::Read(void*, size_t)’:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/././../../support/base64.h:253:19: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  253 |     LOG(FATAL) << "Base64OutStream do not support read";
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/././../../support/base64.h: In member function ‘virtual size_t tvm::support::Base64InStream::Write(const void*, size_t)’:
/home/my_user/workspace/tvm/src/runtime/disco/././../../support/base64.h:210:19: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  210 |     LOG(FATAL) << "Base64InStream do not support write";
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |          

What I am missing here?
PS: here is full cmake output and here is full make output.
